# Custom scroll bar in Internet Explorer 10 (touch) with jscrollpane?

Tags: jscrollpane, internet-explorer-10

We are having issues with jscrollpane custom scroll bars / regions on IE10 (whereas it works perfectly on desktop, android browser, etc).  I have heard this could be due to the differences in touch events implemented by Microsoft in IE 10 as compared to other browsers... does anyone have any insight and perhaps means to repair this functionality?

Even the jscrollpane demo pages don't seem to scroll properly on IE 10 with touch.